# Setting the text of a CCLabelTTF in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

I'm trying to create `CCLabelTTF` where the text changes as the story progresses, but I'm having trouble setting a simple piece of text to it. The label currently displays (null) and I can't seem get it to display "This is text". `NSLog` returns it properly, but the label won't display it. I also made sure the label wasn't destroyed. Here is the code:

```
    CGSize narrativeTextSize;
    narrativeTextSize.width=740;
    narrativeTextSize.height=60;

    CCLabelTTF  *narrativeTextLabel =[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString
                                                                   stringWithFormat:@"%@", narrativeText]
                                                       dimensions:narrativeTextSize
                                                       hAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft
                                                    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
                                                         fontName:@"Helvetica"
                                                         fontSize:20];

    narrativeTextLabel.position =  ccp(255,60);

narrativeText = @"This is text";

//NSLog(@"%@", narrativeText);

[gameMenu addChild:narrativeTextLabel];
```

Comment: `kCCTextAlignmentCenter` is better than `UITextAlignmentLeft` for a parameter `hAliginment:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write

`narrativeText = @"This is text";`   above   `CCLabelTTF  *narrativeTextLabel` ... line.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks. Now how do I change the text if I write a method to change the text, but located below the object...or if I write a method to change it in another layer?

Comment: what you can do is , you can create your label in .h file so it will be global..Now wherever you want to change the text of that label,you can write code like  [yourlabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Updated Text"]];...Hope it helps...

Comment: -(void) changeTextButton {
        narrativeText = @"This is another piece of text";
    }

Comment: If there a way to change the text with a method like something above?

Comment: Inside your changeTextButton method write down this code..-(void) changeTextButton { narrativeText = @"This is another piece of text"; [yourlabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",narrativeText]]; } ,,so here "This is another piece of text"will be printed in a label which is declared in .h file

Comment: I've thought about that, but I'm importing this label into a scene, so ideally, it should reuse the label instead of creating a new one. Maybe there is way to declare it differently so I can just change the text instead of the label.